# Pendulum hanging from moving wagon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, moment-of-inertia

[image]
My Question is: What is the equation describing the angle of the pendulum (theta) depending on the time depending position of the wagon(x(t)).

theta( t, x(t) ) = ?

Note: Neglecting any sort of friction

Comment: What have you tried? In general solving for $\theta$ is not going to be that easy but you can get an ODE for it using Lagrangian methods. If the cart has constant acceleration then @Jithin's solution is correct.

Comment: If you replace the boxcar with Washington State, or Louisiana--and make $m$ a 40 kg fused silica mirror, this problem is relevant to LIGO.

Comment: @jacob1729 An ODE would be lovely

Comment: @S.Pellegrino As this is a homework question it would be good to see some working first. As I said, the quickest route to getting equations of motion would be Lagrangian mechanics I think - do you know this method or are you trying to do it with forces?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the mass of the pendulum to be in equilibrium, the forces acting on it should be balanced.

- Tension in the string $T$
- weight $mg$
- inertia force $m\ddot{x}$

$$T \cos \theta=mg$$
$$T\sin\theta=m\ddot {x}$$
$$\implies tan\theta=\frac{\ddot{x}}{g}$$
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}{\frac{\ddot{x}}{g}}$$